# jQuery check if URL contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
events.on('loaded', function() {
    $('.server_details .start button').click();
});
```

but I only want it to run if the end of the URL is `&autoconnect`, can someone show example of how to do this?

Example URL `http://www.example.com:7778&autoconnect`

Comment: use javascript regex.

Comment: Your example url should be `http://www.example.com:7778/&autoconnect`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the url with `window.location.href`

and then check that using `indexOf`:

```
events.on('loaded', function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("&autoconnect") > -1) {
       $('.server_details .start button').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "I only want it to run if the end of the URL is `&autoconnect`"

I say

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com:7778/&autoconnect';
var param = '&autoconnect';
var valid = url.indexOf(param) == url.length - param.length;
```

If there is a possibility that there may be other parameters as well...

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com:7778/&autoconnect&alsovalid';
var param = '&autoconnect';
var valid = url.indexOf(param) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more correct I suppose.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('url-content') > -1) {
    // Your function do be executed
    }
});
```